# cakephp how to send data from controller to view with json

Tags: php, json, api, cakephp

Hi I'm trying to make an API to send data encapsulating with json.

as cakephp manual said, I added extensions in routes.php

```
$routes->extensions(['json]);
```

and I've made an index function in controller.

```
public function index(){
    $item = $this->Items->find('all');
    $this->set(['items' => $items, '_serialize' => ['items']]);
}
```

here are the problem.

what should i do after this to make api encapsulating with json??

Please help.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Cake 2.x Book (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)

You have to add this to your routes.php file:

```
Router::mapResources('items');
Router::parseExtensions();
```

Then, in your items controller, add the RequestHandler to your components array:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

Then, in your items controller, add your methods, in your example:

```
public function index() {
    $recipes = $this->Items->find('all');
    $this->set(array(
        'items' => $items,
        '_serialize' => array('items')
    ));
}
```

Note: according to model names convention you should call $this->Item instead of $this->Items unless you previously defined the model name as "Item" (singular)  in your item model file.

Finally, the API is done, you can access to yourprojecturl/items.json and see the json result.

Comment: Wow!!Thank you so much for letting me know that. I misunderstood the manual for REST in cake2.x Book. Thank you !!!!!you are awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with RicardoCamacho's code until I used the `$recipes`, which is `$this->Items->find('all');` in the `$this->set(array...`

```
public function index() {
    $recipes = $this->Items->find('all');
    $this->set(array(
        'items' => $recipes,
        '_serialize' => array('items')
    ));
}
```